# How would I check to see if a scoreboard objective is not greater than a certain integer in Minecraft command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Currently I'm trying to create a system that only allows certain command block events to trigger once to each person. Rather than setting up a system at the spawn to set the starting value for the points objective for each new player to 0 I want to create a series of command blocks to check if the player's points value is less than a certain number (to prevent them from triggering it multiple times). I hope that it could also apply to undefined starting values, that way new players could still trigger it the first time as well.

I've come up with an unsuccessful solution

```
/testfor @a[score_points_min!=1]
```

and would appreciate any assistance with this predicament.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `score_points_max` argument. The `score_points` argument selects entities with scores less than or equal to the value. Therefore, the solution is

```
testfor @a[score_points=0]
```

However, this will not work for players with no score at all. You will need to use

```
scoreboard players add @a points 0
```

to give players with no score a score of zero. Alternatively, you could tag players once they max out their score, and only apply the trigger to players without the tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you want exact try:

```
testfor @a[score_points=1,score_points_min=1]
```

etc for whole setup do:

```
/scoreboard objectives create points dummy
/scoreboard players add @p points 1
/testfor @a[score_points=1,score_points_min=1]
```

For example to make trails for specific points you would put this in repeating always active cblocks:

```
/execute @a[score_points=1,score_points_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /particle dripLava ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0.001 100 normal @p

/execute @a[score_points=2,score_points_min=2] ~ ~ ~ /particle totem ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0.001 100 normal @p
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it so when you reach max it goes back to max do it like this:

Say your max is 100,

You place a repeating always active cblock:

```
/execute @a[score_Example=101] ~ ~ ~ /execute @p ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @p 100`
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work.
Repeating always active cblock:

```
/scoreboard players add @a[score_Scoreboard=0] [Scoreboard] 1
```

Anyway more detail:

```
/testfor @a[score_points_min!=1]
```

doesn't work as it's got a `!` instead of it tracking for a min of one and a max of one. Such as my other ones, But if you read my other examples it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a kill counter, You can do the cmd for the kill counter

First do:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Kills playerKillCount Kills
```

Now place a cblock (always active and repeating) with `/execute @p[score_Kills_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @p [Dummy] 1`

Now do a chain onto it with `/execute @p[score_Kills_min=500] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @p[score_Kills_min=500] Kills 0`

I am aware that some of them are not required but that doesn't affect the commands.

Answer (score -1):

`/testfor @a[score_points_max=1]` should work. And for new players, dummy objectives already have a default value of 0. But if you want to test for a null value, you can always use `@a[score_points=]`.

Comment: Neither of these seem to work. The dummy objective doesn't seem to start at 0, that was the initial problem.

Comment: It worked when I tested it.

Comment: noone gets a default value in any scoreboard criteria. as long as you don't assign it in any way, they don't have a score. also, `[score_points=]` doesn't work either.